# CSS Styling not working logically

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, web-applications, vs-web-application-project

I have the following front end code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pn_TSAdmin" runat="server" GroupingText="Timesheet Admin" CssClass="Dashboard_Panel" Visible="false">
    <div id="dv_ProjectSelect" runat="server" style="width:500px;" >
        <asp:Label ID="lb_Project" runat="server" Text="Project:" CssClass="Label" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Project" runat="server" CssClass="Label" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibt_AddProject" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsBottom" ImageUrl="~/Images/add.png" CssClass="ibt_22" OnClick="Click_AddProject" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibt_ProjectStatus" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsBottom" ImageUrl="~/Images/power.png" CssClass="ibt_22" OnClick="Click_SwitchProject" />
    </div>
    <div id="dv_ProjectAdd" runat="server" style="width:500px;" visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="lb_NewProject" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Project Name: " />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_NewProject" runat="server" CssClass="Label" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibt_SubmitNewProject" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/go.png" CssClass="ibt_22" OnClick="Click_SubmitProject" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibt_CancelNewProject" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" CssClass="ibt_22" OnClick="Click_CancelAddProject" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind for ibt_AddProject:

```
protected void Click_AddProject (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dv_ProjectSelect.Visible = false; 
            dv_ProjectAdd.Visible = true;
        }
```

Which is using the following CSS Classes:

```
.Label
{
    width:200px;
    margin:10px auto 10px 20px;
}
.ibt_22
{
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px 10px;
}
```

dv_ProjectSelect shows up as expected with the items lining up perfectly.

However when I click ibt_AddProject the items aren't showing correctly in dv_ProjectAdd as per the following picpaste showing the screen transition(http://picpaste.com/DumbCSS-173MxC30.jpg)

I've seen things mentioned about adding cursor:text and also z-index:999 but nonbe of which have helped with this issue.

Any idea why this is happening and how I could go about resolving it so it looks correct.

Comment: You have `ImageAlign="AbsBottom"` for image buttons in first div, but not in second. Is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks Andrei - Its one of those things when you look at it for ages and can't see the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: Is that was the issue you should probably indicate it somewhere, just to bring some clarity to the thread. Not everyone reads comments these days, you know.